# Visual Studio 2017 - Creating a C# Console App (.NET Framework) with Solution and Location

Tags: visual-studio

This started out as a question and after hours of searching, I stumbled across the answer. I thought someone else who runs into the same issue may find this useful so I'm posting the answer.

**The  original question:**

I am  new to Visual Studio 2017 and am having difficulty figuring out how to create a Console App (.NET Framework) with Solution and Location.

When I select File > New > Project > Visual C#, I am presented with two Console App choices. The one I want, Console App (.NET Framework), only gives me the choice of Name and Framework. I want (like in Visual Studio 2015) to be able to select Name, Location, Solution and Solution name for the .NET Framework.

If I chose Console App (.NET Core) I can see all the options I want at the bottom. How can I get the Console App (.NET Framework) to give me the options for Location, Solution, etc?

Comment: You could just post an answer to your own question

Answer (score 0):

**The answer:**

Go to the following location: Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > General

and make sure that 'Save new projects when created' is checked